# Extracting records using SQOOP in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am facing issues in extracting data for more number of records using SQOOP in  Hadoop eco system (CentOS Linux)

If we try to do import for 50 records in a table, it runs successfully and data gets imported within seconds to cluster.
If we try for 100 records, it doesn’t show any progress. PFA the terminal output for success and failed scenario. PFB the sqoop command issued for the same.

```
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /tmp/mapred/local/1426570684848/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar <- /root/Desktop/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized hdfs://10.192.25.223:9000/opt/Installations/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar as file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684848/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/mapred/local/localRunner/root/job_local320009395_0001/job_local320009395_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
15/03/17 11:08:05 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/mapred/local/localRunner/root/job_local320009395_0001/job_local320009395_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684831/netty-3.4.0.Final.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684832/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684833/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684834/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684835/commons-io-1.4.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684836/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684837/paranamer-2.3.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684838/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684839/sqoop-1.4.4-cdh5.1.3.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684840/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684841/avro-ipc-1.7.5-cdh5.1.3-tests.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684842/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684843/ojdbc14.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684844/avro-1.7.5-cdh5.1.3.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684845/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684846/avro-mapred-1.7.5-cdh5.1.3-hadoop2.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684847/xz-1.0.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/tmp/mapred/local/1426570684848/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local320009395_0001
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local320009395_0001_m_000000_0
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15/03/17 11:08:05 DEBUG db.DBConfiguration: Fetching password from job credentials store
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 1=1 AND 1=1
15/03/17 11:08:05 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating db record reader for db product: ORACLE
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO db.DBRecordReader: Working on split: 1=1 AND 1=1
15/03/17 11:08:05 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBRecordReader: Using query: select * from TBAADM.REFERENCE_CODE_TABLE WHERE rownum<300 and ( 1=1 ) AND ( 1=1 )
15/03/17 11:08:05 DEBUG db.DBRecordReader: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
15/03/17 11:08:05 INFO db.DBRecordReader: Executing query: select * from TBAADM.REFERENCE_CODE_TABLE WHERE rownum<300 and ( 1=1 ) AND ( 1=1 )
15/03/17 11:08:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local320009395_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/03/17 11:08:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/03/17 11:08:45 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:08:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:09:15 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:09:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:09:55 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:09:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:10:25 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:10:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:11:05 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:11:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:11:35 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:11:41 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:12:15 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:12:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
15/03/17 11:12:45 DEBUG mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread reporting progress
15/03/17 11:12:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give your Hadoop and Sqoop versions and the sqoop command you are trying to execute.

For now, your problem might be related to the question answered here:
[Job keeps running in LocalJobRunner under Cloudera 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454938/job-keeps-running-in-localjobrunner-under-cloudera-5-1)